# Data fundamentals question for averaging percentages

Tags: statistics, average, percentages

So I have a script which records buying and selling transactions from a table, for each transaction it records the % difference so something like this (Table 'A'):

```
|    date    |  time | price | transaction_type | id
| 2023-02-11 | 17:40 |   10  |      'buy'       | 1234-564-gtfA
| 2023-03-11 | 17:45 |   15  |      'sell'      | 1234-564-gtfA
| 2023-02-11 | 17:40 |   20  |      'buy'       | 1234-564-gtfB
| 2023-03-11 | 17:45 |   22  |      'sell'      | 1234-564-gtfB
| 2023-02-11 | 17:40 |   10  |      'buy'       | 1234-564-gtfC
| 2023-03-11 | 17:45 |   17  |      'sell'      | 1234-564-gtfC
```

it would record in another table (Table 'B'):

```
|    date    |  time | perc_diff | id
| 2023-03-11 | 17:45 |     50    | 1234-564-gtfA
| 2023-03-11 | 17:45 |     10    | 1234-564-gtfB
| 2023-03-11 | 17:45 |     70    | 1234-564-gtfC
```

So when I'm creating aggregate statistics originally I was just averaging over the perc_diff column to get the "total" average % change but when instead using the raw transaction numbers. I.e. summing the sells then subtracting the buys, dividing by the total_sale it's a completely different number. 35% for using the raw transactions, 43% averaging the perc_diff column.

I *know* that this makes sense like intuitively but I can't figure out why it doesn't work.

Anyone good at math want to explain it to me like I'm the dummy that I am?

Comment: It helps to understand what you have before doing calculations. Does anybody of your team has a table schema description? Do anybody are willing to help?

Comment: You don't say what it is that you're buying and selling, but if it is (for example) stocks, bonds, or mutual fund shares, you typically don't just buy one unit of each thing at a given price, you might by $500$ units of one thing at price $10$ (total investment $5000$) and $100$ units of something else at price $20$ (total investment $2000$). If you then compute the average gain of the entire portfolio, you'll get another percentage which likely won't match either of the two percentages you already computed.

Comment: The general idea, however, is that if you just average the percentage increases from different transactions, you're treating all transactions as if they have the same potential impact on your overall profit; but if you actually put half your money into purchase B then it will have more influence on your profit than either of the other two purchases. For a more extreme case, if you put $98\%$ of your funds into one purchase and $1\%$ into each of the other two, you should expect your profit for the month to be determined almost completely by the large purchase.

Comment: Anyway, that's what *I* consider to be the intuitive explanation. The strict mathematical explanation is you work out a problem like this one and see that the numbers don't match, and that is **rock solid proof** that the two methods of averaging are not equivalent.

Comment: @DavidK Thanks, I did consider that (but forgot to mention here) I'm buying/selling fractional shares which are all $100 worth, admittedly there is some small variance but it doesn't match the change in %s. It is for sure rock solid proof, I just wish I understood better why...

Comment: The reason I'm asking for numbers of shares is to try to figure out what the example actually says. Did you spend twice as much money to purchase the fractional shares of B as on fractional shares of A? And the same amount on C as on A?